# Put value in random place in matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I create an axb matrix with this function:

but I'm getting an error that's saying that my values are out of range.  Is it because I use two equal signs instead of 1? Thanks

Comment: You've used an equality test instead of an assignment here: `board[row_index][col_index] == [val, False]`

Comment: Ummm... You deleted the entirety of your original code.  How can we know why you are getting a value out of range?  Shouldn't that be a new question anyway?

Answer (score 2):

```
board[row_index][col_index] == [val, False]
```

should be

```
board[row_index][col_index] = [val, False]
```